# How to update quantity of my current table when new data is inserted to another table?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

How do I update my Quantity in my Books table when inserting new data to my Borrow table? I'm working on our thesis and it is about Library and this borrow feature is giving me a headache. I have a borrow form that when I press the "Borrow" button, data is inserted to Borrow table, while doing that, I want the quantity of books in my Book table to be deducted or reduced by the quantity that is inputted in my Borrow form.

For example. On my SearchBook form, there is 17 in my Quantity and if I press "Borrow" it will prompt a new window (Borrow form) with the details that must be complete and of course with the Quantity. Upon click "Borrow" the data will be saved on my Borrow table and the Quantity on my Books table will be deducted with the quantity that has been stored to the borrow table.

Is there any way to do this? Can I have some help, please? Here is my code:

Borrow form

```
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
    Dim myDate As Date = dtpBorrowedDate.Value

    Try
        With cn
            .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Library Management System\bin\debug\LMS_Database.accdb"
            .Open()
        End With

        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Borrow] ([ID_Number], [First_Name], [Middle_Name], [Last_Name], [Course], [Year], [Contact_Number], [ISBN],[Book_Title],[Book_Author],[Category],[Year_Published], [Quantity], [Borrowed_Date], [Library_Card]) VALUES ('" & txtIDNumber.Text & "', '" & txtFirstName.Text & "', '" & txtMiddleName.Text & "', '" & txtLastName.Text & "', '" & txtCourse.Text & "','" & cboYear.Text & "', '" & txtContactNumber.Text & "', '" & txtISBN.Text & "', '" & txtBookTitle.Text & "', '" & txtBookAuthor.Text & "', '" & txtCategory.Text & "', '" & txtYearPublished.Text & "', '" & cboQuantity.Text & "', '" & dtpBorrowedDate.Value.ToString & "', '" & cboLibraryCard.Text & "')"

            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@ID_Number", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 30, Me.txtIDNumber.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@First_Name", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.txtFirstName.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Middle_Name", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.txtMiddleName.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Last_Name", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.txtLastName.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Course", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.txtCourse.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Year", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.cboYear.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Contact_Number", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.txtContactNumber.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@ISBN", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.txtISBN.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Book_Title", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.txtBookTitle.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Book_Author", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.txtBookAuthor.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Category", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.txtCategory.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Year_Published", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.txtYearPublished.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.cboQuantity.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Borrowed_Date", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.dtpBorrowedDate.Value.ToString))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Library_Card", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.cboLibraryCard.Text))

            cm.Parameters("@ID_Number").Value = Me.txtIDNumber.Text
            cm.Parameters("@First_Name").Value = Me.txtFirstName.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Middle_Name").Value = Me.txtMiddleName.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Last_Name").Value = Me.txtLastName.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Course").Value = Me.txtCourse.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Year").Value = Me.cboYear.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Contact_Number").Value = Me.txtContactNumber.Text
            cm.Parameters("@ISBN").Value = Me.txtISBN.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Book_Title").Value = Me.txtBookTitle.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Book_Author").Value = Me.txtBookAuthor.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Category").Value = Me.txtCategory.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Year_Published").Value = Me.txtYearPublished.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Quantity").Value = Me.cboQuantity.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Borrowed_Date").Value = Me.dtpBorrowedDate.Value.ToString
            cm.Parameters("@Library_Card").Value = Me.cboLibraryCard.Text
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MsgBox("Book borrowed.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success!")
            Me.txtIDNumber.Text = ""
            Me.txtFirstName.Text = ""
            Me.txtMiddleName.Text = ""
            Me.txtLastName.Text = ""
            Me.txtCourse.Text = ""
            Me.txtContactNumber.Text = ""
            Me.txtISBN.Text = ""
            Me.txtBookTitle.Text = ""
            Me.txtBookAuthor.Text = ""
            Me.txtYearPublished.Text = ""
            Me.txtCategory.Text = ""
            cboQuantity.SelectedIndex = -1
            cboYear.SelectedIndex = -1
            cboLibraryCard.SelectedIndex = -1
            Exit Sub
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Please fill all the details needed. ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
    End Try
```

Comment: You should start with some research on the correct way to use Parameters.  Your SQL has the values screwed into the query but then you supply parameters.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Sorry. But to be honest, our school doesn't really teach us how to code and the this was given to me without any knowledge. I just collected some codes in the internet and made it work. This is why this is so hard to me. I'm a total beginner on this. But thanks! :)

Comment: Never use code you dont understand.  The first thing you should have done was look up some of those objects and methods to see what it does.  There is massive amounts of info on MSDN as well as many thousands of posts here with code showing how to use them.  Read **[ask]** and take the **[tour]** to help get the most out of SO

Comment: Ideally, Quantity would not altered in table but instead the total books not borrowed would be calculated when needed. Might take a look at the Microsoft Lending Library database template.

Comment: In a library db each book should be a record in Books. Its status as borrowed or not borrowed would be changed. Calculate totals in aggregate query.

Comment: Actually, even the borrowed/available status could be calculated based on whether there is an active 'borrowed' record. This record would identify who and when book was borrowed and later input when the book was returned.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. What I have done may be a dumb thing. But I got it working. Thanks, mate!